# "Unable to read TLD from JAR file" when run spring boot app on heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-boot, tld

I wrote an springboot app running at Heroku.
When I run locally with `maven spring-boot:run` everthing is ok.

But when I deploy the app to Heroku, the page show error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp (line: 3, column: 0) /WEB-INF/jsp/common.jsp (line: 3, column: 64) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/spring.tld" from JAR file "jar:file:/app/target/slog-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar": java.io.IOException: Unable to open root Jar file 'jar:file:/app/target/slog-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

And I run the jar locally with "java -jar target/*.jar" have the same error.

this is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>ort.stv</groupId>
<artifactId>slog</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Spring Boot Blog System</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSR303 BeanValidator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- GENERAL UTILS begin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- GENERAL UTILS end -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        <classifier />
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.10.4</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I change to war packaging.and deploy by heroku's war uploading method. like `heroku deploy:war --war target/app.war`

Comment: I find a better way to deploy spring boot app to heroku. first change package to war at pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to deploy spring boot app to heroku.

first change maven package to war.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/log4j-${log4j.version}.jar</warSourceExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

then change `Procfile` to **`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.war`** .

solved :D.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [known limitation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) in Spring Boot and an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/367) related to using JSPs with embedded containers.  Long story short, it's not currently supported.  However, the Spring Boot reference documentation links to a [GitHub example project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) they claim gets it working.

Comment: Thank you for reminding，I changed the jar packing to war packaging.and deploy use heroku's war deploy method. like `heroku deploy:war --war target/app.war`